# Inconsistent accuracy with the =FLOOR() equation in Excel

Tags: excel, time, rounding, floor

I am working on an audit that is reviewing billing practices at my workplace; we have been given data sheets that provide a start time and end time of services, and a rule set to follow in regards to units billed **(15 minutes = 1 unit)**.

My role in this is to look at what was billed or not billed, find the true amount of units that should have been billed, and then identify the accuracy or inaccuracy of what the billing department charged the insurance company in terms of unit value.

My solution to this was to create columns of data with these headers:

**Start Time,  End Time,  Minutes Elapsed,  True Total Units**

(there are more headers within the table but they don't play a factor in the solution).

The minutes elapsed cell would have the equation **=(([@[End Time]]-[@[Start Time]]))*1440**. This was to convert the hourly amount that would be extracted from the start and end times to minutes.

The true total units cell would have the equation **=FLOOR(([@[Minutes Elapsed]]/15),"1")**. The rounding portion of this is where my confusion comes in. We need the rounding to ensure that we are not accidentally rounding up and billing, for example, 7 units for 104 minutes when it is supposed to be 6 units. The problem I am encountering is that some of the answers coming back are inaccurate due to the rounding portion of the equation, and I am not sure why.

**examples:**
3:20 pm - 5:10 pm is 110 minutes. with the above equation in place, the total true units comes out to 7, which is accurate.

3:30 pm - 4:45 pm is 75 minutes. with the above equation in place, the total true units comes out to 4, which is incorrect.

alternatively, 3:45 pm - 5:00 pm is 75 minutes as well. with the above equation in place, the total true units comes out to 5, which is accurate.

3:45 pm - 4:00 pm is 15 minutes. with the above equation in place, the total true units comes out to 0, which is incorrect.

I appreciate any help that can given towards this; I'm sure that whatever I'm looking for as the solution is probably a minor change in the equation to set things right. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up the data you gave in a table with the same column names. If you look at the attached image, you'll see that I changed the format on "Minutes Elapsed" to show roughly 15 digits out. This shows that the result of the equation weren't quite integers; however, they were close enough to be displayed as such with fewer digits.

In my "Column2", I used the equation **=ROUND([@[Minutes Elapsed]],0)** to round the minutes to the nearest integer. My column "Fixed" is using the same equation in "True Total Units", just referencing "Column2" instead of "Minutes Elapsed": **=FLOOR(([@[Column2]]/15),"1")**.

[image: pictured data]

So the simplest fix, would probably be to change the "Minutes Elapsed" equation to **=ROUND((([@[End Time]]-[@[Start Time]]))*1440,0)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! this was the solution; I really appreciate the feedback.